# Set Google Chrome as the debugging browser in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, google-chrome

When I press F5 in Visual Studio 2008, I want Google Chrome launched as the browser that my ASP.NET app runs in. May I know how this can be done?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Right click on an .aspx file and click "Browse with..." then select Chrome and click "Set as Default." You can select more than one browser in the list if you want.

There's also this really great [WoVS Default Browser Switcher Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/).

Comment: Assuming you can actually find chrome.exe, that is.  On my Windows XP PC, it's buried at `C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.

Comment: Yes, for server-side code. It will not let you debug JavaScript, that only works in IE. For server-side debugigng, VS attaches to the IIS worker process, not the browser itself.

Comment: The extension seems to be gone.

Answer (score 52):

1. Go to the visual studio toolbar and click on the dropdown next to CPU (where it says IIS Express in the screenshot). One of the choices should be "Browse With..."

   [image: Visual Studio Toolbar]
2. Select a browser, e.g. Google Chrome, then click Set as Default

   [image: Browse With...]
3. Click Browse or Cancel.

Comment: This is the simplest of all from Visual Studio GUI.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it stored the default browser for all subsequent debug/run without debug sessions.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: What toolbar is that? My Debug tool bar doesn't have the dropdown or the configurations. I'm using VS2019 16.6.5.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I just needed to Reset the Standard toolbar. It wasn't displaying correctly for some reason.

Answer (score 27):

To add something to this (cause I found it while searching on this problem, and my solution involved slightly more)...

If you don't have a "Browse with..." option for .aspx files (as I didn't in a MVC application), the easiest solution is to add a dummy HTML file, and right-click it to set the option as described in the answer. You can remove the file afterward.

The option is actually set in:
C:\Documents and Settings[user]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio[version]\browser.xml

However, if you modify the file directly while VS is running, VS will overwrite it with your previous option on next run. Also, if you edit the default in VS you won't have to worry about getting the schema right, so the work-around dummy file is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Are you the original source or is this your source: https://newbedev.com/set-google-chrome-as-the-debugging-browser-in-visual-studio


If you are, thanks for the lead.


But this is slightly wrong, it should be browsers.xml: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\[version]\browsers.xml

Answer (score 16):

For MVC developers,

- click on a folder in Solution Explorer (say, Controllers)
- Select Browse With...
- Select desired browser
- (Optionally click ) set as Default

Answer (score 5):

If you don't see the "Browse With..." option stop debugging first. =)

Answer (score 2):

in visual studio 2012 you can simply select the browser you want to debug with from the dropdown box placed just over the code editor

Comment: That option will be the there if you have the "standard" toolbar visible

Answer (score 2):

For win7 chrome can be found at:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

For VS2017 click the little down arrow next to the run in debug/release mode button to find the "browse with..." option.

Comment: The little down arrow...nice

Answer (score 2):

Click on the arrow near by start button there you will get list of browser. Select the browser you want your application to be run with and click on "Set as Default" Click ok and you are done with this.

Answer (score 2):

For the new versions of Visual studio, click on the dropdown next to the dropdown of "IIS Express".

[image]

Now simply choose `Browse With` and choose Google Chrome, and click `Set as default`.

[image]

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this because the "Browse With" option was not I was looking for as that did not allow me to debug.  I had not changed browser debugging in a while and just forgot that I needed to click the arrow here...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Visual Studio 2019: To change default browser
type defaults in home, then click browser.

See this picture:

[image: defaults apps]

[Reference/Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/31013/browser-selection-in-visual-studio-2019.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: OK, done I have added more detail.

Comment: Answer must  be self contain, use link only for reference.  Your answer still under link only answer and deleted soon.

Comment: OK, done I have added more detail, thanks for your feedback