# Silverlight 4 & VS 2010: Debug Symbols not loading

Tags: silverlight, debugging, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

So about half the time I hit `F5` and start to debug my silverlight app in VS2010 the debug symbols don't get loaded. There doesn't seem to be any method to this madness...

Has anyone else had similar issues, and if so did you/how where you able to resolve them.

Thanks!

Edit:

I was using chrome, so I switched to IE, however I'm still getting the same issues.

Comment: What browser are you using? I have had issues whenever IE is not my default browser for debugging Silverlight apps from VS.

Comment: Chrome. That may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found out how to do this, and I never posted it, because I'm a bad community member.

What I ended up doing was attaching the debugger manually to chrome.  NOT the chrome instance that has the web page, but the chrome instance that is running Silverlight (which is a separate process)

I haven't had any problems since.

Comment: Yes! Chrome works when IE doesn't. VS 2010 Ult also has an option under the web deployment project properties | Package/Publish Web tab, Switch to debug | Set Items to deploy to "All files in this project" instead of the default.

Answer (score 7):

With IE it should work without any problem but you need to turn on Silverlight debugging in the "web" project (i.e. the one that hosts your Silverlight application). Open the project properties and got to the "Web" tab: At the bottom you have to check the Silverlight checkbox.

Not really your question but I mention it anyway:
FireFox can be made to work with [this](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Firefox-Debug-Helper-%28Visual-Studio-Add-in%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677318/how-to-debug-silverlight-against-google-chrome) you find some information about debugging in Chrome.

Comment: Man...after 2 days of trying everything, even uninstalling all Silverlight stuff and reinstalling..I finally saw this post before I was gonna post my own question..Thanks a billion. It should be possible to specify which browser I want to use while debugging in VS. VS should not use the default browser always