# How to switch default browser for debug asp.net in visual studio 2008 / 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, browser

Since system install the default browser was opera but suddenly become IE in both 2008 and 2010 versions. Default browser in my system is opera. How I can switch make Opera default for debug again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **Visual Studio 2010** you can **right click** any aspx file in **Solution Exlorer** and you get an option of **Browse With** in the **Context menu**. Select **Browse with** and you get the **list of browsers** in the system. There you can select the **default browser**.

Comment: How about on a project without .aspx files (non Web Forms, I guess); such as an ASP.NET Web API app? It's using the browser I set my system to use (Chrome), but I want to test my app running on IE, too...

Answer (score 0):

Add an otherwise unneeded HTML page to your app via right-clicking the project and selecting Add > HTML Page, then right-click that page and select "Browse With" For more detail, see Runscope API Tools' answer here: [Set Google Chrome as the Debugging Browser in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154/set-google-chrome-as-the-debugging-browser-in-visual-studio)